# Linux symbolic link when file is deleted and recreated

Tags: symlink

Does a symbolic link to a target need to be deleted and created again if the target gets deleted but is then recreated with the same name ? I suspect not, but I wanted to be sure, as this situation seems to be analogous to the data of the target changing without the target being deleted and recreated.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a symlink is just a special text file:

```
$ ln -s 123 x
$ ln -s //../ y
$ ls -l x y
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 3 Jul 17 00:26 x -> 123    # size: 3 bytes
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 5 Jul 17 00:26 y -> //../  # size: 5 bytes
```

Dereferencing of a symlink happens only when the symlink is actually accessed. (Internally, `readlink(2)` is used for that.)

So symlinks need not to be recreated in your scenario. This is only the case for hard links (e.g., created by `ln target link`).

Comment: For soft symlinks we need to recreate the sym link?

Comment: @tuk No. Actually, there's no such thing as "soft symlinks". Symlinks in general are sometimes called "soft links" (which is not really a term) in contrast to "hard links" (which is a term).